# Restful web API Security

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, restful-authentication, api-design

Scenario:
We have a MS SQL DB which holds content for various sites/apps - we plan to create a c# .net web api and then build in REST calls from our sites/apps (these are typically all client side code). Some sites/apps have a user login and some do not

Problem:
- how do we go about securing the api so only our sites and apps can access it
- how do we build in to cope with and without a user login

Any suggestions and thoughts welcomed

Comment: Just use IdentityServer4.

Answer (score 0):

Generate JWT token for each app assign it to your Apps(Like APP secret), which call your rest API, using authorization header or create any custom header in API Call.

Comment: for this I would require and authentication server correct? like this - https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec

Comment: Yes, But with little change since you want your "apps" to have access to api, you need to create a token for each app, so that it can be used to authenticate your apps.

Comment: So basically you will create app secret, and now with each request you will pass two token 1) Token for user, 2) Token for apps, something Like Oauth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to open your webapi for 3rd party usage. One quick way could be

1. Create a certificate and deploy on all servers
2. From Server1, generate hash of sometext e.g. hello.
3. Send this hash to Server 2 in header or querystring.
4. At Server 2, validate this hash.

In case, there are plans to open webapi for 3rd party usage then secure your endpoints using oAuth. I would recommend using IdentityServer4.